# Blur part of pdf front page

Tags: pdf, image-processing, imagemagick

I have a site that sells PDF files. I want to be able to preview PDF documents to users, but showing the the first page of the PDF file, with the bottom 80% or so blurred so you can't make out its content

I want the blur to fade a little, without a harsh transition.

I figured I could use something like

```
convert -density 200 test.pdf[0] image.jpg
```

To convert the frontpage to an jpg file. I am not sure where to go from here.

I saw a guide where they first produced a black/white gradient, and then applied the blur somehow using

```
  convert -size 75x75 gradient:black-white blur_map_gradient.gif
  convert koala.gif blur_map_gradient.gif \
          -compose blur -define compose:args=3 -composite \
          blur_koala_gradient.gif
```

But haven't been able to make it work

Any advice?